# Is sharepoint versioning stored inside the document for excel documents?

Tags: sharepoint, vba, sharepoint-2007, excel, versioning

Does anyone know if SharePoint stores it's version numbers inside the files for Excel files?  I would assume that it does not.  This is what I need:  I have an Excel file stored in a SharePoint document library.  The file will eventually be distributed and must be able to function offline.  The file is somewhat macro-intense, and I would like to be able to log the version number of the file within the file so that if there are errors, the version number would be known or even recorded in another place.  Is there a way to access the version number within VBA without accessing a web service?

Comment: Do you have the option of upgrading to SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Right now I am on 2007.  We are in the process of testing the upgrade, so we should have it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You MIGHT be able to try something where on the SharePoint ItemUpdating event you update the XLSX file to reflect the version number you want. I have not tried using the OM to update the Excel document, but I have with word, not with updating a version number.

Comment: Thanks, this issue ended up being lower priority, and so was not implemented.